# Append search parameters in url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to filter some stocks. Basically, `search` parameters in url trigger different graphQL calls to get the right filtered content.

My url looks like this: `localhost:3000/stocks?orderBy=id_stock&orderWay=asc&page=1`

I have a form that lets you select your wanted filters. Let's say you want every item with the color with an `id_color = 1`, I want that on form submit, `&color=1` appends to the existing url, to give: `localhost:3000/stocks?orderBy=id_stock&orderWay=asc&page=1&color=1`.

Is there a way to do this simply? I tried working around `this.props.history.push()` but it does not seem like that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

`history.push()` and `history.replace()` is the only way to programmatically change the URL in react router. If you want to append something to the current path you can simply do something like follows.

```
this.props.history.push(this.props.match.url + "&color=1")
```

`this.props.match.url` gives you current path and here we basically create the new path by appending the new param to the current path.